# Purpose of this code (XmlElement)XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, api, xml-parsing

I'm working on a web service API for one of our customers. I've never touched this code before and the original developer is no longer with the company.

```
      XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
      xDoc.LoadXml(xmlReply);

      XmlElement element = (XmlElement)xDoc.GetElementsByTagName('TagName')[0];
```

What is the purpose of the `XmlElement` class name inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple casting operation.  The point of this is to cast the result of the method call to the type `XmlElement`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a casting. `GetElementsByTagName` returns `XmlNodeList`, which have items of type `XmlNode`. `XmlNode` is a base class of `XmlElement` and need to cast it to `XmlElement`.